# How export from access to database mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

It's easy with me to  export data from excel to MySql using php, but how can export data from access to MySql  with php, what is the best way, and how can export some specific field only to specific field in MySql?

Comment: One specific field is not an export. select from one db, update the other.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-export.html).
It should be what you are looking for without recoding everything (which would be the safest way.